# Time complexity of the iterative algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time, time-complexity

This is the algorithm: I think its time complexity is O(nlogn) but i am not sure

```
k=1;
while (k<=n) do      
    j=1;
    while (j<=k) do        
        sum=sum+1;
        j=j+1;
    k=k*2;
```

Comment: What is the pattern of the inner-loop count?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inner loop at the first time performs 1 iteration, at the second 2 iterations. The sequence goes like 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, ... as long as it is smaller than or equal to `n`. The sequence may have `Θ(log(n))` elements but its sum is `Θ(n)`. This is because

> 1 + 2 + 4 + ... + 2^k = 2 * 2^k - 1

and we know `n/2 < 2^k <= n`. So the inner loop is performed `Θ(n)` times 
and each inner loop execution requires constant number of instructions.

The rest of the code is just `log(n)` assignments to `j = 1` and
`log(n)` doubles of `k`.

So the time complexity of the algorithm is `Θ(n)`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The O(NlogN) upper bound is of course also true by that argument, but the facts about the sum of geometric progression (N+N/2+N/4+N/8+...<2N in this case) allow to establish a better estimate.

Comment: Having spent a bit of time (a bit too much time) measuring it, I have to agree that it is linear.  Over a range of 15 doublings in the problem size, the ratio of two successive times was between 1.90 and 2.15, with no obvious pattern to the 'more than 2' and 'less than 2' factors, especially not over multiple runs.  The machine I was testing on was not completely idle, which accounts for some of the variability.

Answer (score 0):

```
// code                 | max times executed
k=1;                    | 1
while (k<=n) do         | log n
    j=1;                | log n
    while (j<=k) do     | log n * n
        sum=sum+1;      | log n * n
        j=j+1;          | log n * n
    k=k*2;              | log n
```

So the O complexity would seem to be n log n.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth The reasoning is correct, just suboptimal (we can do better). O(n log n) is technically true by definition (upper bound on complexity) even if O(n) is also true.